# Is x != 0.0 a safe check against DivideByZeroException?

Tags: c#, divide-by-zero

In order to prevent DivideByZeroException in C#, people often write things like

```
double f(double x) {
  if (x != 0.0) return 1000.0/x;
  else return 0.0;
}
```

Given the fact that floating-point arithmetic always has imprecisions, I wonder whether it is guaranteed that this function never throws a DivideByZeroException.

Comment: Why dont you just catch DivideByZeroException and return 0.0 in the catch?

Comment: Hmm, no, intentionally generating garbage calculation results is very unwise.  You'll want to *throw* a DBZE, test the result for double.IsInfinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dividebyzeroexception%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) says:

> Dividing a floating-point value by zero will result in either positive infinity, negative infinity, or Not-a-Number (NaN) according to the rules of IEEE 754 arithmetic. **Floating-point operations never throw an exception.** For more information, see Single and Double.

So yes, "it is guaranteed that this function never throws a DivideByZeroException." - even without any checking, but it may return positive infinity, negative infinity, or Not-a-Number (NaN) even if you check for `0.0`, for example when you divide a rather large value by a really small value so that the result exceeds the range covered by double.

Answer (score 8):

It wouldn't throw a `DivideByZeroException` anyway, as you're dealing with `double` arithmetic - it would just return infinity. Other values may return infinity, e.g. `f(double.Epsilon)`.

Comment: Wouldn't it return double.NaN?

Comment: @Dervall - No, http://kossovsky.net/index.php/2010/04/division-by-zero-is-simple-but-the-result-not/